# Debugging visual basic dll library from asp.net hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, debugging, com

I have the following problem. 
I have some project written in Visual Basic (not Visual Basic .NET but simple Visual Basic - sic!). I can compile it and generate a dll. 
Then inside my web application I add reference to this dll library. When I run my web application hosted in default Visual Studio server, everything is fine and I can debug my Visual Basic project. However, when I host my web application in IIS then I can't. Code does not stop in my breakpoint. 
My asp.net catch the exception when I try to execute some method from the mentioned library which is something like:

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'xxx' to interface type 'yyy'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{4C2875B5-3265-306B-9C74-1BEC98986B1A}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).
```

Can someone please help me because I've been struggling for 2 days without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you debugging using "Attach to Process"?

**First determine the w3wp.exe process:**

For IIS6

- Start > Run > Cmd
- Go To Windows > System32
- Run `cscript iisapp.vbs`
- You will get the list of Running
  Worker ProcessID and the Application
  Pool Name.

For IIS7

- Start > Run > Cmd
- Go To Windows > System32 > Inetsrv
- Run `appcmd list wp`

Note the Process ID (PID).

**Next in Visual Studio:**

- Debug > Attach to Process...
- Find the w3wp.exe with the right PID and attach

Your breakpoints should work.